# grails redirection fom spring security loginpage:not working

Tags: spring-security, grails-2.0

I edited the default view of spring security ui. to the theme matching to my web. and created a link in edited spring security ui to a new controller and action . But the link is not working.

the controler and action is mentioned below,

```
class seccontroller {
    def register()
        {
            render(view:"new_user");
        }
}
```

And the redirecting link created in auth.gsp is gven below.

```
<g:link controller="sec" action="register">New user..?</g:link>
```

But when the link clicks.. the page remains in auth.gsp ie; in login page itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this answer here with a view of contributing a solution to such problem , for a fresher using grails.

It remained in login page itself since i didn't gave any static rules in in spring security config, so if i define static rules in config file then it will redirect to that new link according to that rule. Static rules can be define in config file as given below

```
      grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/':                              ['permitAll'],
        '/sec/register':                  ['permitAll'],
        '/500':                           ['permitAll'],
]
```